# post discharge from hospital call

Tags: traducción

How would I say:

> I'm calling to follow up with you, to see how you are doing since your discharge home.
>   My supervisor likes to reward our employees for a job well done, is there anyone in your opinion that stood out that you would like to thank or acknowledge?

Comment: Welcome to Spanish.SE. We are not a translation service. Having said that, we are happy to help you with translation questions, but please show some effort on your part, and ask a *specific* question regarding your area of trouble or doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Estoy llamando para hacerle un seguimiento y ver como le está yendo después que fue dado de alta. Mi supervisor quiere estimular a nuestros trabajadores por el trabajo bien hecho. ¿Hay alguien en su opinión que debería ser reconocido?.

**NOTE:** Questions asking for translations are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not provide a bulk translation service.

Please

Comment: That translation wasn't even right, you would say "dar seguimiento" instead of "hacerle un seguimiento"

Comment: @AndreiD In Spain, at least, we would say *hacer un seguimiento*, which means to evaluate and control something or (as in this case) someone continually or periodically. *Dar seguimiento* would be to perform an action that follows on a previous one.

Comment: I agree with @gorpik and I'm from cuba